# How can I conditionally redirect to a page in NextAuth?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, next-auth

There are 2 points of signin for a user of my site, the first is my app and the second is a link from a 3rd party site. If they are coming from the 3rd party site, they should be redirected back to it.

The only way I can think of to "tell" my app that they are coming from a 3rd party is to add a query param to the sign in link.

For example, the 3rd party will have a link like:

`https://myapp.com/signin?comingFrom3rdParty=true`

and I want to use this query param in the signIn callback to basically say after sign in is successful:

```js
if(comingFrom3rdParty) {
  // redirect back to 3rd party
} else {
  // redirect to my apps dashboard
}
```

I don't know if query params are the correct approach to this but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing i can think of using `document.referrer`

```
useEffect(() => {
    const referrer = document.referrer;
    if (referrer !== null) {
      console.log(`I was redirected from ${referrer}`);
      // you can redirect the user here 
    }
  }, []);
```

if you have two different apps running on port 3000 and 3001. in app port:3000 have this component

```
const Test = () => {
  return (
    <Link href="http://localhost:3001">
      <button className="rounded bg-red-600 px-9 py-2 text-white">
        Let's go
      </button>
    </Link>
  );
};
```

when you click on the button, you will be redirected to `http://localhost:3001` and check the console